# Add to array Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to create an array with points 500-700. The total space in the array is 200. What am I doing wrong?

```
int[] anArray = new int[200];

for (int j = 0; j <200; j++){
    for (int h = 500; h <700; h++){
        anArray[j] = h+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: are you having an error ?

Comment: When I print the anArray[2] it prints 700

Comment: You have two for loops for no good reason.
Try:
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) anArray[i] = i + 501; //

Comment: for starter if you want values from range 500-700 inclusive, you array with length 201

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The effect of your current code sets all elements of `anArray` to 700. You're looking for something much simpler:

```
for (int j = 0; j <200; j++)   
    anArray[j] = 500 + j;
```

Comment: You're welcome! I hope you understand why your nested for loop didn't do the trick?

Comment: I'd rather do 'anArrray.length' then declare 200 as an int.

Answer (score 0):

your do not need an inner loop!

just add 500 to j.

so in the inner loop it should be anArray[j] = j +500;

Answer (score 0):

You are using a nested loop, thus your array is running out of space.

Just do the following

```
for (int j=0;j<200;j++)
{
  anArray[j] = j+500;
}
```

Note: I assumed that you do not want 700 in the array. If you do, just increase the space by one

Answer (score 0):

you are iterating 200 times from 500 to 700, this is not what you are expecting...

Do instead:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
            System.out.println(j);
            anArray[j] = 500 + j;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, actualy you write values in [500..700) in every cell of array. 
That code do exacly what you want:

```
int size = 200;
int[] anArray = new int[size];
offset = 500;
for (int j = 0; j <size ; j++){   
   anArray[j] = offset + i; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're after the ability to add integers 500 through to 700 you could try the following:

```
int[] anArray = new int[200];

for (int j = 0; j <anArray.length; j++)
{
    anArray[j] = 500 + j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] anArray = new int[200];
    int plusWith=500;
        for (int j = 0; j <200; j++){
                  anArray[j] = j+plusWith;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not solving the problem with your algorithm, but as an alternative solution:

```
int[] range = IntStream.rangeClosed(500, 700).toArray();
```

Requires Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's working :

```
iteration 1 :
value of j is 0
then the inner loop will iterate from 500 to 700 and at the last 
the value of anArray[0] which is the first element will be set to 700.
```

Same will happen to the other iterations, well still you are getting the different values ranging from 600 to 700 in some array elements 
**because j is increasing and range to set the values is decreasing**

Thats why you should use a single loop here as @Kenney explained.

I hope You understand. :-)